# How to run unit test in parallel by modules using Maven?

Tags: maven, testing, parallel-processing

Are there any form to run unit test with surefire in parallel but by module? For example, we are using build in parallel by defining number of threads. Can we apply this techniques by defining number of threads to execute test in parallel by module. For example, firstly, the project is compiled. Secondly, we can use compiled project for run our tests by following form: mvn -T 4 test?

Answer (score 1):

There is a different between running the build parallelized and the tests parallelized. The first one is done by using the -T option but the test can be configured in [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).